# MVC Razor view: XML node parsing issue

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, razor, xpath

I have an MVC application which is querying a Lucene/Solr index. In a partial view, I am displaying metadata on a series of XML documents returned from the query. The metadata is extracted from the XML documents using XPath queries and is paged, listing 10 documents at a time. The view cshtml is as follows...

```
@model SolrMVCTest2.Models.Facet

<section>


@foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode doc in Model.SearchResult.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc"))
{
 <article>
    <b>Document type:  @doc.SelectSingleNode("//str[@name='docType']").InnerText  </b>  <br />
    <b>NHS Number:  @doc.SelectSingleNode("//str[@name='crn']").InnerText  </b>  <br />
    @doc.OuterXml.ToString()
</article>
<p></p>

}
</section>
```

I have included a display of the OuterXML for debugging purposes and a partial listing of the results highlights a serious issue. FOr each group of 10 documents, the innertext of the selected nodes is not updated for each successive document, but always displays the values from the first document of the set of 10 as shown in this partial result....

```
Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2jr001002</str><str name="crn">7024326654</str><str     name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2ju001002</str><str name="crn">0437861414</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2k1001002</str><str name="crn">7626346416</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2mp001002</str><str name="crn">2637403616</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2nm001001</str><str name="crn">0874706416</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2qq001002</str><str name="crn">1867082616</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2ss001001</str><str name="crn">5436985416</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2yi002003</str><str name="crn">8731654606</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">mh00k2yr001001</str><str name="crn">0906133416</str><str name="docType">MedicalHistory</str></doc> 


Document type: MedicalHistory  
Patient Number: 7024326654  
 <doc><str name="id">op00k23e001001</str><str name="crn">6335192616</str><str name="docType">OutpatientAnnotation</str></doc>
```

The Patient Number display (extracted from the str element named "crn" is not updated obn the second and successive documents, and the Document Type (fromt he docType element) is not updated on the 10th.

Does anyone have any ideas which may explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this behavior, because your inner xpath starts from double slash `//`:

```
@doc.SelectSingleNode("//str[@name='docType']")
```

This means global search over the xml document, and it will return first found `str` element which matches your search no matter where it is in document. That's why you always see data of first `doc` element.

Use xpath without double slash to get `str` element of current `doc` node:

```
@doc.SelectSingleNode("str[@name='docType']")
```

---

Also consider following - instead of parsing data in view, create view model, which will contain required data:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And create documents in controller

```
var documents = 
      from doc in SearchResult.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc")
      select new Document {
          Type = doc.SelectSingleNode("str[@name='docType']").InnerText,
          PatientNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("str[@name='crn']").InnerText
      };

return View(documents);
```

Comment: The modified XPath works OK. I thought the \\ syntax would be alrght as the doc variable was a single node form the parent XML and should therefore only have had a single element named crn or docType, but it seems the XPath is traversing the parent XML bot just the doc node. I am displaying the documents this way rather than using a model built in the controller as this is very much a prototype, and the final structure of the documents (and therefore the model and classes) has not been finalized. In fact there will eventually be many more types of document,each with a different structure.